# Multiple mat4 by vec4 and then make it vec3 in Python

Tags: python, c++, numpy, matrix, vector

Please help me. How can I multiply `mat4` by `mat4` and then make it `vec3` in `Python`? Here is an example of what I need in `C++`:

`glm::vec3 var = glm::vec3((mat4(...)* glm::vec4(0, 0, 0, 1)));`

As well as a failed attempt on `Python`:

`var=pyrr.Vector3( pyrr.matrix44.create_from_translation(pyrr.Vector3([20,0,5])) * pyrr.Vector4([0,0,0,1]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `@` operator.

```
var=(pyrr.matrix44.create_from_translation(pyrr.Vector3([20,0,5])).T @ pyrr.Vector4([0,0,0,1])).xyz
```

The `@` operator is described in [PEP-465](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/)

Comment: Unfortunately, i still get this error: `cannot reshape array of size 4 into shape (3,)`

Comment: please also note that there is a `.T` at the end `create_from_translation()`